How to verify downloaded Fedora installation file against the checksum files?
I have downloaded Fedora to my macOS Catalina. I then followed the steps outlined here to verify the downloaded file against the checksum files. Step 4 says to run the following command: sha256sum -c *-CHECKSUM. However, there doesn't seem to be a sha256sum on macOS Catalina, so I ran the following command instead: shasum -a 256 -c *-CHECKSUM. The output was:
shasum: Fedora-Workstation-40-1.14-x86_64-CHECKSUM: no properly formatted SHA1 checksum lines found

Does it mean the downloaded file is corrupt? How can I properly verify the downloaded installation file against the checksum files?

you can always just manually verify:
shasum -a 256 yourdownloadedfile.iso

should simply give the same checksum as your -CHECKSUM file (which is a plain text file) contains.
